# How to get back a Header in Wordpress once removed?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

At first i wanted to remove the Header on a few pages. I used this code:

```
/* Hide Header Menu for ()/ */
.page-id- #header-space, .page-id- #header-outer {
    display: none;
}
.page-id- #header-secondary-outer {
    display: none;
}
.page-id- #footer-outer {
    display: none;
}
```

I now can't figure out how to bring the header back to these pages, i deleted the code from 'Appearance - Editor) but that didn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean with "didnt seem to work"? Was the code away but the problem stayed or does the deletion didnt work

Comment: You need to check few things to get started:



1. can you see the Header element in the DOM tree? (right click on your page [somewhere close where it is supposed to be] -> inspect element -> and find it).
2. If is there (i assume it is), select it and check out his CSS properties. If there’s a `display: none` it will tell you also where it is defined

Comment: @Jonasw Yes i managed to delete the code however the problem still stayed and the Header did not come back which is what i expected to happen. pumpkinzzz I've taken these steps but am unable to find the Header element in the DOM

Comment: @lauren askew: then theres no header, wich makes it difficult for us to find a solution for you

Answer (score 1):

```
display: block
```

should do it.
display: block is the opposit of display: none.

Comment: display:block did it! Thank you for your help :)